# AnewKodi AC1200 - Ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.17.0-041700-generic

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 18.04

I bought this [wifi usb adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07BKVB4KK) and I installed the drivers without problems but usb wifi acapter doesn't turn on the light and I can't scan 5ghz wifi. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried with an official kernel?

Comment: Which driver did you install? May we see the link? Were there any errors or warnings when you installed it? Why not just use the internal device? It seems to be working correctly. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Fixed! At the end it was a wrong driver. The correct driver for that usb adapter is: rtl8822bu

I used this fork for compiling 4.15+ kernel:

https://github.com/FomalhautWeisszwerg/rtl8822bu

I hope it helps more people.

Thanks for your help!

Regards.

Comment: @helektron you can post an answer! Please do so instead of editing the question if you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**An answer by the OP**

At the end it was a wrong driver. The correct driver for that usb adapter is: rtl8822bu I used this fork for compiling 4.15+ kernel: github.com/FomalhautWeisszwerg/rtl8822bu I hope it helps more people.